# NekoHTML SAX fragment parsing

Tags: java, html-parsing, sax

I'm trying to parse a simple fragment of HTML with NekoHTML :

```
<h1>This is a basic test</h1>
```

To do so, I've set a [specific Neko feature](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/faq.html#fragments) not to have any HTML, HEAD or BODY tag calling startElement(..) callback.

Unfortunatly, it doesn't work for me.. I certainly missed something but can't figured out what it would be.

Here is a very simple code to reproduce my problem :

```
 public static class MyContentHandler implements ContentHandler {

     public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
         String text = String.valueOf(ch, start, length);
         System.out.println(text);
     }

     public void startElement(String nameSpaceURI, String localName, String rawName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
         System.out.println(rawName);
     }

     public void endElement(String nameSpaceURI, String localName, String rawName) throws SAXException {
         System.out.println("end " + localName);
     }
 }
```

And the main() to launch a test :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException {
       SAXParser saxReader = new SAXParser();
       // set the feature like explained in documentation : http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/faq.html#fragments
       saxReader.setFeature("http://cyberneko.org/html/features/balance-tags/document-fragment", true);
       saxReader.setContentHandler(new MyContentHandler());
       saxReader.parse(new InputSource(new StringInputStream("<h1>This is a basic test</h1>")));
  }
```

The corresponding output :

```
HTML
HEAD
end HEAD
BODY
H1
This is a basic test
end H1
end BODY
end HTML
```

whereas I was expecting

```
H1
This is a basic test
end H1
```

Any idea ?

Comment: If you set the feature to be false, do you get exactly the same output?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it !

Actually, I was parsing my HTML string in a GWT application, where I've added the gwt-dev.jar dependency. This jar packages a lot of external librairies, like the xercesImpl. But the version of embedded xerces classes does not match the one requiered by NeokHTML.

As a (strange) result, it appears that NeokHTML SAX parser didn't use any custom feature when using gwt-dev embedded xerces version.

So, I had to rework some code to remove the gwt-dev dependency, which by the way is not recommanded to be added to any standard GWT project.

Comment: To be more specific, gwt-dev.jar includes NekoHTML in version 1.9.13, which is bugged with fragment parsing. Fragment parsing works with 1.9.11 and 1.9.14, no luck :-(